# Output the result after processing in RxJava2

Tags: java, kotlin, concurrency, rx-java2

I asked the same question, just for Thread - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67047918/output-the-result-after-processing-in-a-thread/67048130#67048130)

The program has a thr () function that implements RxJava2 and I need the function to return a variable after being processed in subscribe ().

```
fun main() {
    println(thr())
}

fun thr(): String {
    var x = "Before thread"
    Observable.subscribe(
         {
              x = "After thread"
         },{
              x = "!ERROR!"
         }
    )
    
    return x
}
```

The desired result is - "After thread"
The current result - "Before thread"

If this were simply implemented through Thread, then the join () function could have been used, but looked in the documentation and could not find an alternative function.
If there are any suggestions on how to solve this problem, then it would be great.

Comment: You would use `blockingGet()` to do this, but depending on the context, that might cause a thread to block which you don't want to be blocked. If that's the case, your `thr` method needs to return `Observable<String>`, not `String`.

Comment: @dano , Thank you very much for your reply. I also wanted to know how I can get exactly a String from Observable<String>,when I call thr()? .toString()?

Comment: You would call `.blockingGet()`. But keep in mind that in a lot of cases, you should not be using `blocking*` operators, and should instead write your applicaiton so that it never takes values of their `Observable` container. So your application will mostly be made up of APIs that return Rx types, eventually leading to an "entry point" that subscribes to the Rx chain.